# $list = $(list) declaration in jquery mean

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anybody explain what this declaration mean in jquery `$list = $(list);`
 Is there any way this can be declared in plain javascript also?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery

Comment: Questions like these indicate that even the minimum due diligence read up hasn't been done.

Comment: Obviously it cannot, because it uses the `jQuery` function. However, in plain JavaScript you can just omit it since this assignment will be a No-op if you're not using `$list` anywhere (and that should be a relevant part of your question).

Comment: _"Is there any way this can be declared in plain javascript also?"_ `$list` and `list` are both valid JavaScript variable names. `$` is a valid JavaScript function name. So that statement calls a function `$()`, passing it the variable `list` as an argument, and assigns the return value of the function to the `$list` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the `list` variable is a DOM element, so pass it to `$` function make it a jQuery object:

```
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var $list = $(list);
```

This is usefull when loop through some elements:

```
$('.elems').each(function () {
    // `this` is dom element
    // so we'll pass it to `$`
    var $elem = $(this);

    // now I can use jQuery methods on it       
    $elem.css('background', 'yellow');
});
```

---

Some people (as myself), declare the variables which is jQuery object with a `$` at the start:

```
var $hello = $('#hello');
```

In this case, whenever I see a variable like `$hello`, I'm sure that it is a jQuery object. However this is not the standard rule for all programmers.

Answer (score 0):

`$list = $(list);` is declaring a variable for a DOM object.

it could also be displayed as `var list = $(list);`.

Comment: How do you know it's a DOM object? `list` sounds more as if it was an array.